# Solving a transcendental equation consisting of a quadratic part and a part involving inverse Lambert W functions

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, roots, exponential-function

## Question statement

I would like to solve the following equation in the two variables $x$ and $y$:
\begin{gather}
0 = x^2 - a y^2 + i b [x y - W^{-1}(x)W^{-1}(y)] ,
\end{gather}
where $a$ and $b$ are purely real parameters, and $W^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse Lambert W function of $x$. Domain constraints exist due to physicality: for all physical solutions $y$ is purely imaginary, and for some physical solution $x$ is purely imaginary.

## Answer attempt

Put the above equation in the alternative form thus:
\begin{gather}
0 = x^2 - a y^2 + i b x y (1 - e^x e^y) .
\end{gather}
Then, by inspection (separate terms into pairs), we have at least the solutions
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
\text{(i)}&\text{ } x = \sqrt{a} y \text{ and } y = \frac{2 i n \pi}{1 + \sqrt{a}} \text{, where } n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{,}\\
\text{(ii)}&\text{ } x = - \sqrt{a} y \text{ and } y = \frac{2 i n \pi}{1 - \sqrt{a}} \text{, where } n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{,}\\
\text{(iii)}&\text{ } x = - i b y \text{ and } y = \frac{\operatorname{Log}(- a / b^2)}{1 - i b} \text{, and}\\
\text{(iv)}&\text{ } x = - i \frac{a}{b} y \text{ and } y = \frac{\operatorname{Log}(- a / b^2)}{1 - i (a / b)} .
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
The method of this answer attempt is quite obviously not general; hence I post. I might ask more specifically: Can we prove that (i) to (iv) are the only solutions? and if not, is there a more elegant method that derives all solutions?

## Thanks

I extend sincere thanks for any help.

Comment: It's possible to show (using just the intermediate value theorem) that the equation has a solution with $x \in \mathbb R$ and $y=(2n+1)\pi i$, but I don't think they'll be easy to write down explicitly.  I've been thinking about how to find an approximate formula but I've had no luck with that either.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment!

I hadn't thought of proving solution domains, which is definitely a good idea. Would you be able to outline how you used the Intermediate Value Theorem?

I was wondering about approximations as well. It would be nice if one could prove solution domains for which particular approximations are valid, but alas I too have had no luck yet.

Comment: Sure.  There are some cases to check (when $a$, $b$, and $n$ are positive and negative) so let me just do one of them.  Suppose $a>0$, $b>0$, and $n\geq 0$.  If $y = (2n+1)\pi i$ then $$\begin{align}&f(x,y) = x^2-ay^2 + ibxy(1-e^x e^y) \\&\qquad= x^2+a(2n+1)^2\pi^2-\pi bx(1+2 n)(1+e^x) \to -\infty\end{align}$$ as $x \to +\infty$ and $f(0,(2n+1)\pi i) = a(2n+1)^2\pi^2 > 0$, so $f(x,(2n+1)\pi i)$ has a zero with $x>0$.

Comment: Once again, I thank you! Your idea is clever. It is not obvious to me how to find for $y = (2 n + 1) \pi i$ an expression for $x$, nor if there is an appropriate approximation one can use at this point, although I've just had beer with dinner. Nevertheless, the nice, albeit possibly unsurprising, result is that my solutions (i) to (iv) are definitely not the only solutions. So this is something to go on. Thanks!

Comment: Introducing the new variables
\begin{gather}
q =_\text{Df.} x + \sqrt{a} y \text{ and } r =_\text{Df.} x - \sqrt{a} y \nonumber
\end{gather}
the governing equation looks slightly more symmetric:
\begin{gather}
0 = q r + i \frac{b}{4 \sqrt{a}} (q^2 - r^2) (1 - e^{(1 + 1/\sqrt{a}) q / 2} e^{(1 - 1/\sqrt{a}) r / 2}) .
\end{gather}
I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Using the basic idea behind the [method of dominant balance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Method_of_dominant_balance) I can get a good approximation for the solutions mentioned in [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414953/solving-a-transcendental-equation-consisting-of-a-quadratic-part-and-a-part-invo#comment890931_414953).

Let $a>0$, $b>0$, and $y=(2n+1)\pi i$.  By expanding the parentheses the equation becomes

$$
a\pi^2 + 4 a \pi^2 n + 4a\pi^2 n^2 - b\pi x + x^2 - b\pi xe^x - 2b\pi nx - 2b\pi nxe^x = 0.
\tag{1}
$$

Numerically it appears that as $n \to +\infty$ the root $x$ also tends to $+\infty$ so let's go ahead and assume this.  The two largest terms in the equation are then $4a\pi^2 n^2$ and $-2b\pi nxe^x$, so as $n \to \infty$ the equation is approximately the same as

$$
4a\pi^2 n^2 - 2b\pi nxe^x = 0
$$

or, upon dividing through by $2\pi n$,

$$
2a\pi n - bxe^x = 0.
$$

This has an explicit solution

$$
x = W(2\pi n a/b),
\tag{2}
$$

which appears to give a good approximation for the solutions of $(1)$ as $n \to +\infty$.  This approximation appears to get better when the ratio $a/b$ is large.

If you'd like you can get a more elementary leading order approximation by using the known asymptotic

$$
W(q) \approx \log q - \log \log q + \frac{\log \log q}{\log q} + \cdots
$$

as $q \to \infty$.

**Numerics.**

Let's fix $a=b=1$.  In the plots below $n$ is on the horizontal axis.

The blue dots in this plot are the numerical solutions of $(1)$ for $x$ when $n=1,2,\ldots,40$ and the black line is the asymptotic solution $(2)$ we obtained.

[image]

This second plot shows the absolute error between the numerical solutions to $(1)$ and the asymptotic solution $(2)$ for $n=10,11,\ldots,5\times 10^4$.  The $n$-axis is plotted with a logarithmic scale for clarity.

[image]